# Populating Fields in InfoPath using the People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I've got an InfoPath form and have set up a Data Connection to enable me to retrieve details of a persons account using the people picker.

I've got the First Name/Last Name/Department and Job Title. When I open up the People Picker the only fields I'm getting are Display Name/AccountId and Account Type (as pictured).

[image]

Is there a way of getting the information I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get it with the UserProfile webservice of sharepoint.  (_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx)

f.e:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this:

Unfortunately the UserProfile webservice no longer works in Sharepoint online and produces error 5566.

The best work around for this I've found would be to use a data connection to the hidden User Information List on the root of your page.

So step-by-step:

- Add a new data connection for User Information List at the stem of your site
- Select the needed fields (in your case First_name, Last_name, Department and Title)
- Leave "Store a copy of the data in the form template" unchecked and click "Next >"
- Uncheck "Automatically retrieve data when form is opened" to query based on selected users, instead of downloading all user data
- Create Rule on change (no condition) on your First and Last Name fields and run the following actions in them:

  - Set a field's value for first and last name:

    - in "Field" select queryFields First_name/Last_name of your data connection
    - in "Value" select your first/last name field
  - Query using a data connection your Sharepoint List data connection or to User Information List data connection to find any user in the members AD group
  - Set a field's value on your people picker:

    - in "Field" select the Displayname of your forms people picker (only available in advanced view)
    - in "Value" select the dataFields > People Picker > Displayname of your data connection

Hope that helps, I'll edit to include pictures soon.
Please let me know if you wanted to set First name, Lastname, Department and Job title based on the people picker, because this would also be possible. Thank you in advance!